# Hash password in xamarin to match database hashed password

Tags: c#, xamarin

Im very new to xamarin, and currently I need to hash my user password before sending it to the api to verify as sending the plain text over the web is a security risk.

In my web application i use Microsoft.AspNet.Identity to hashpasswords and save them to the database

```
 public UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager { get; private set; }

string strPasswordHash = UserManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(viewModel.Password);
```

Im trying to get the same hash algorithm as this but im unsuccessful. So i would like to know if this is possible to get the same hash in xamarin somehow

So when hashing the following test password "TestP@ssw0rd" i would get "AKtowbhuu47Dn4Pk8r4SM4zKo6P7N/N27afp6aDBL4sroWzOiXucrSG6kiHrjU2Ayw==" so how would I in xamarin hash the same password send it to my api which uses the Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.PasswordHasher() to verify the 2 hashed passwords.

Comment: You really should be encrypting your hash on the client side salted with a nonce generated on the server side - and then have the server decrypt the plain-text and have it generate the hash using the server's salt (different from the nonce). Otherwise if you do the hash client side then any one intercepting the hash could just use the hash directly themselves - it's just like getting the password.

Answer (score 0):

use using System.Security.Cryptography

```
 public string MD5Hash(string input)
    {
        System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Managed sha512 = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Managed();

        Byte[] EncryptedSHA512 = sha512.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Concat(input, securityCode)));

        sha512.Clear();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(EncryptedSHA512);
    }
```

Input is your plaintext and securityCode is salting password to create secured hashcode,
you have to define and assign securitycode

Comment: This help, but also doesnt atm, as i use Microsoft.AspNet.Identity to hash passwords and save them to the database, i know it salts them etc, but what would i enter as the security code to get the same hash in my xamarin project send it to my api which will compare them, cause at the moment it fails as they not the same.

Comment: Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.PasswordHasher() use random salts for generate hashcode so every time you will get different hashcode and in xamarin you can use System.Security.Cryptography it will generate same hashcode every time

Comment: Okay thanks, i understand a bit more now, but can you please explain what will i set the securityCode as, will this be the code as to what the string is encrypted as

Comment: The issue that im still getting is that when i send the hashed password to the database and send it through my method than compares the two hashes its still returns false as the hashes dont match up. even when i enter a security code like 24

Comment: use securityCode like "MART2SBNNI99212" and dont compare hash in client side is not safe way, just send the generated hashed to database server and match in database directly query like select user_id from user where id=@id and password=@password where password is hashed code that coming from client side id and hashed code matched the it will return user_id